# javascript Date() sum day but not month

Tags: javascript, date

I want sum 30 days in `Date()` object, I've used javascript `Date()` and set new date with `.setDate(.getDate()+30)` and it seems to have updated the month when you print it with `console.log()` but when I try to get the values,

```
var myDate = new Date();

myDate.setDate( myDate.getDate() + 30 ); 

console.log( myDate ); // will show 1 month ahead
console.log( "Next Month (wrong): " + myDate.getMonth() ); // will thow this month! why???

var dateData = {
  'day':(myDate.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + myDate.getDate() : myDate.getDate(),
  'month':(myDate.getMonth() < 10) ? "0" + myDate.getMonth() : myDate.getMonth(),
  'year':myDate.getFullYear()
} ;

console.log( dateData.year + "-" + dateData.month + "-" + dateData.day ) ;
// it sum date but not month
```

ps.: today is august 28. + 30 days it should be 07
it will output in console:

```
Date 2017-09-27T18:07:56.101Z  Scratchpad/3:14:1
Next Month (wrong): 8  Scratchpad/3:15:1
2017-08-27 // this should print 2017-09-27 but the month still 08
```

what's wrong? is this a javascript fault or a programmer mess?

Comment: Adam's answer is correct, but on a side note... don't mutate Date objects. Just don't. Just make a new one. Do yourself a favor and pretend that Dates don't have setters.

Comment: I agree with @JaredSmith. You're much better off using a library like https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @JaredSmith—I don't think that's good advice at all, you need to backup such assertions with reasoned argument.

Comment: @RobG I have never heard anyone express the contrary position about dates before. So here's my argument: 1. There's no real performance hit to just making a new one in 99.99% of cases. 2. Conceptually, a date is a value: Tue Aug 29 2017 07:21:38 is always Tue Aug 29 2017 07:21:38 in the same way that the number 5 is always five. I'm not such an fp stickler that I'd say all mutation is bad always but we don't program with mutable strings anymore even though they are `char*` under the hood (or unicode pts), and I think it's unnecessarily complex to mutate Dates.

Comment: @JaredSmith— 1 is as compelling as "Buy this car, it's *nearly* as fast as the other car, therefore it's better." 2 is irrelevant. Given a date *d* you're suggesting that `new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() + 1)` is preferred to `d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)`. If mutation is bad, then join the TC39 committee and remove assignment operators like `+=`, `*=`, etc. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I get the feeling someone has preached immutability at you too strongly/often. I'm sorry if that happened: I wasn't trying to punch your buttons. I still think my advice to the OP is good general advice, but that's all it is: *advice*. Moses did not come down from Mt. Sinai with "Thou shalt not mutate thy Date objects" carved into stone tablets. To the extent that the fashionistas of the programming world are trying to make it dogmatic rather than heuristic, well, I'd agree that's a bad thing. YMMV. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. JavaScript counts month on a 0 based index. 0 = January, 1 = February, etc. September is month 8, not 9, so your code is correct.

Try this:

```
console.log(new Date().getMonth()); // During August, will be 7
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 0):

The [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) function returns values from 0 to 11.

Comment: This is different from the existing answer....how? It even links to the same documentation.

Comment: Fair enough. I hadn't spotted the answer prior to posting.